# Calling MPI_Barrier twice in same function is this okay to do?

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi, message-passing

Using OpenMPI in C;

Say I'm have

```
main()
{
MPI_Init();

//// Important Program Region

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

// do something here

MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

////
MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Is this bad practice? Can I force synchronisation in forcing barriers twice like this? Any disadvantages of doing this?

Comment: How is this the same line of code? I see two separate lines of code calling `MPI_Barrier`. Why do you think that you need a barrier there in the first place?

Comment: Whoops, thanks for pointing it out, now for my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above program should work as is. It is perfectly acceptable to force synchronization via `MPI_Barrier` not just once or twice, but for as many times as you want. With that said, the major disadvantage of `MPI_Barrier` is that the scalability of your program will be significantly lesser the more times you call it.

Note: If you call it on the "same line" as suggested in the title (but not the question itself), then the second barrier is effectively a no-op - you've already hit a synchronization point; what exactly is the second barrier going to do?

Comment: Sorry about that, the "line" thing was a typo, I fixed it